# Recommended physics book(s) that uses calculus and have difficult problems

Tags: classical-mechanics, education, calculus

What physics book(s) uses calculus and has complex problems (undergrad/olympiad level)?

Context:

I've read "Fundamentals of Physics by Halliday and Resnick" and I found the problems to be fairly straightforward and not so challenging.

I am a high school student and I've finished the physics curriculum in my school, also I am studying Calculus 1 and linear algebra.

I've experienced that studying calculus-based physics helps me understand calculus and its application.

Answer (score 1):

*University Physics* by Young & Freedman has so-called "challenge problems" that are intended to challenge even the strongest students. You could try those. (Warning: they really are difficult.)